# Angular - unable to watch if within ng-switch-when

Tags: angularjs

I need to $watch a variable on the scope but it is never called. 
I found it has something to do with ng-switch-when.

For example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/gGKGX/

```
angular.module("GuyModule",[]).controller("GuyController", function($scope) {

    $scope.something = "foo";

      $scope.guy="This is guy";

    $scope.$watch('guy', function(){ console.log("guy changed!"); }  );

} );


<div  ng-controller="GuyController" ng-app="GuyModule">
    <div ng-switch="something">
        <div ng-switch-when="foo">
            <input ng-model="guy"/>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="bar">
            <button ng-click="something='bar'">Click me!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect "guy changed!" to be printed but it is not, when I remove "ng-switch-when" it works. 
How can I work through this?

By the way - same thing happens with ui-if (from the angularui project).

Comment: That is very strange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guy is in the scope of the switch as well as your controller.

As you can see in the picture, `guy` exists in both scopes.  When editing it, you are editing it within the scope of `ng-switch` and it is not editing the one you are watching

[image: Scope]

Another example is displaying guy outside of the switch: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/gGKGX/1/

**To fix this**: Add `$parent` to `guy` that is in the switch (`$parent.guy`): http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/gGKGX/2/